# How to edit the default makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

Can I edit the default makefile? I want to add the `-std=c++11` flag to the default makefile so that the `make` command will compile and build C++11 programs.

For example, currently, when I try to compile a program with the `make` command, these errors occur:

```
g++ a.cpp -o a

a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

a.cpp:118:12: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘it’ with no type [-fpermissive]

  for(auto &it : v) cout << it << endl;
            ^

a.cpp:118:17: warning: range-based ‘for’ loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
  for(auto &it : v) cout << it << endl;
                 ^

<builtin>: recipe for target 'a' failed

make: *** [a] Error 1
```

Comment: Open the `Makefile` and add your flag to the `CPPFLAGS` variable if one exists. But most Makefiles have those variables

Comment: where can i find the makefile ? i don't write any makefile, i just run "make a" in the terminal, where a.cpp is the filename..

Comment: Then the `Makefile` should be in the same directory where you called make.

Comment: actually i'm asking  how to edit default makefile, which can be viewed using  "make -p -f /dev/null"

Comment: Hmm I think you can't change this. But you can try the following `make 'CPPFLAGS+=-std=c++11'`

Comment: There is no "default makefile". The built-in rules are called built-in rules because they're built-in. You can download the source to gnu make and modify that, if you really must.

Otherwise, create a makefile in your source directory and just put `CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11` in it, and the built-in rule will use it.

Comment: Also, it's unwise to modify machine-wide behavior for this case, because the choice of which language standard to use is specific to the code you're writing under that standard. Soon you will be writing for C++1y or later, and your global choice of C++11 will be a problem. If you change the global setting you will break recompiling your older code; if you leave it as C++11 globally, you will have to work around that to compile your newer code. So put it in a makefile in each source directory and you'll never have to change it unless you revise the code to match a different standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass additional arguments to `make` that will override the default values.

```
$ make [TARGET]... [VARIABLE=VALUE]...
```

In your case, you want to add the `-std=c++11` switch to the C++ compiler.  The flags for the C++ compiler are stored in a variable named `CXXFLAGS`. So you could try this.

```
$ make a CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11'
```

Note that the variable `CPPFLAGS` does *not* hold the flags for the C++ compiler but for the C (and C++) pre-processor. So if you add the `-std=c++11` switch to it, you'll get a bad surprise if the C compiler gets called with it.

Actually, since the `-std` switch fundamentally modifies what language the compiler accepts, I prefer to think of it not as a compiler flag but a compiler selection, so I prefer to override the `CXX` variable that holds the name of the C++ compiler.

```
$ make a CXX='g++ -std=c++11'
```

This also has the advantage that you keep any other compiler flags such as `-Wall -O2 -g` or what have you.

Comment: Don't forget that you can add to the compiler flags with `+=`. Like this: `CXXFLAGS+='-std=c++11'`

Answer (score 1):

Create a `makefile` in your directory with the source code if you haven't already done so -- and empty file will do for starting.

In your makefile, add a line with

```
CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11'
```